# jQuery Validation remote method phone validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to use remote to validate a phone number to a json service

this is my rules:

`smsMobilePhone: {
        required: true,
        number: true
        remote: {
            url: '' + baseURL + 'validations/phone',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': +token + ,
            },
            // processData: false,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                value: function() {
                    return $("#smsMobilePhone").val();
                }
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                if (data.isValid === true) {
                    console.log(data.reason);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        smsMobilePhone: {
            required: "Please enter your phone number",
            number: "Please enter a valid phone number"
            remote: {"Remote reason"}
        }
    }`

the the thing is, now I'm sending `/validations/phone?smsMobilePhone=xxxx&value=xxxx` but the server expected `/validations/phone?&value=xxxx`, so it never validates.

By default the remote method uses the selector in use as de first parameter, in this case `?smsMobilePhone=xxxx`, but what I wanted to achieve is to is to make the following request without the selector name `?&value=xxxx`.

The service replies {isValid: false, reason: "Phone specified is not valid in a country."}

Is there a way to send the right parameter and get the reason to remote message?

Comment: As it appears from the code above, the `data` that's sent to the server only contains `value` and not `smsMobilePhone` as you say. However, that's what the server expects anyway, right - only `value`? But if the server is specifically checking for `3332`, there's little that you can do to get a valid response other than inputting that value in `smsMobilePhone`. One other thing that you can check is whether the server expects `GET` or `POST` method.

Comment: Thank you, I've edit my question the server expects a number and one parameter before it value, and also the method is Get. The thing is know the input selector is being sent, instead of value has the server expected.

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't follow the question properly. Unfortunately, the comment sounds a bit contradictory to the question, so I'm not very sure. If you want to add another parameter to the query string, then you could either (1) Change the `url` (like `url: '' + baseURL + 'validations/phone?smsMobilePhone='+$("#something").val()`) to include the additional parameter; or (2) Add it inside `data` by concatenating the required parameter with `return`. This is just a guesswork based on what I can understand from the question so far. Hope that helps somehow...

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't explained very well, by default the remote method uses the selector in use as de first parameter, in this case `?smsMobilePhone=xxxx`, but what I wanted to achieve is to is to make the following request without the selector name `?&value=xxxx`.

Comment: What do you mean by “selector”? Are you talking out the GET parameters? And what do you mean by “but I want to do it without X”? Does the API you are using allow for that?

Comment: When you make a remote rule the first parameter is the id(selector) of the input by default in this library, but my API expects 'value=(phone number being typed) I was looking for a way to work around this

Comment: I guess you'll have to change the URL as follows: `url: '' + baseURL + 'validations/phone?value='+$("#smsMobilePhone").val()`. And, with that, you can get rid of the `data` segment.

Comment: yes but for some reason when I do that:  `url: '' + baseURL + 'validations/phone?value='+$('#smsMobilePhone').val()+'' ` the actual request being sent is `validations/phone?value=&smsMobilePhone={typed number}`

Comment: Sorry @PauloB, it's kind of hard to understand how this could be now. Your code `data: {
                value: function() {
                    return $("#smsMobilePhone").val();
                }` already suggests that the parameter passed should be named `value`, but apparently that's not what's happening? I was thinking to suggest one more possible attempt.. which is... renaming all `smsMobilePhone` to `value` in your HTML and JS. However, I've to say, I'm very reluctant with this change.

Comment: Thank you @DhruvSaxena I've done that previously and it works as expected, but it's not really a solution because I have other elements in the form to validadate in the same manner. I think I'll do a second ajax validation with no plugin for these particular cases after the first local ends.